# Getting error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysqli

My code is very messy, but I am trying to make a forum on my website.

```
<?php 
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection Failed");
    }
    mysqli_select_db($conn, 'forum');
    $get= "select * from forum";
    $runq = mysqli_query($conn, $get);
    while($fetch_value=mysqli_fetch_array($runq)){
        $get_usr_name=$fetch_value['username'];
        $get_body = $fetch_value['info'];
        }
        $result = $conn->query($get);
        if(is_null($get_body)){

        }
        else{
        echo "<div id='inputform1'>";
        for($row = 1; $row < $result->num_rows; $row++){

            $dbhost = "localhost";
            $dbuser = "root";
            $dbpass = "";
            $dbname = "forum";
            $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                die("database connection failed: ") .
                    mysqli_connect_errno() .
                    " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")";

            }
            $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, "select info from forum where id='$row';");
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, "select username from forum where id='$row';");
        echo "<strong class=\"after_username\">by: {$result}</strong><br><br><p id=\"bodyforum\">{$result1}<br><br></p>";
        }
        echo "</div>";

    }
    ?>
```

I cannot seem to post the username and password; it keeps saying:

> Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

I have tried many different "tactics" but none of them seem to work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Why run the same query twice?

Comment: chris85 is correct: You can use `select info, username from forum where id='$id'"` to avoid two queries. However, `$id` should be taken from the query result; you're assuming all IDs for rows your query returns will return start at 1 and increment regularly. This is not likely to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

The returned value of a mysqli query is a result object. It's not just a set of rows; it also contains information on the query, success or failure, error messages, and other things. You need to use the [result object's methods](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) explicitly to access the rows returned by your query.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is from this line

```
echo "<strong class=\"after_username\">by: {$result}</strong><br><br><p id=\"bodyforum\">{$result1}<br><br></p>";
```

The `$result` and `$result1` are not strings. You need to loop it up and then access the records.

Comment: oh okay, thank you! i tried it and it worked for me.